# Why does setting action_controller.perform_caching = true break javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my environment file, setting:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

causes javascript not to load at all.

The only javascript_include_tags i'm using are in three different view files and declared as such:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.timeago', 'application', 'rails_custom', :cache => 'common'
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'rails_custom', :cache => 'common'
= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.validity.pack', 'jquery.timeago', 'application', 'rails_custom', :cache => 'common'
```

But the first and third ones are never included in the same request.

After setting the variable in the environment above, while hitting the application, a request for common.js is made and the server returns it, but Firefox gives a syntax error on it, claiming that a significant chunk of the file is not a function.

Under what circumstances would caching cause the combining of the javascript files to become invalid?

Comment: Turns out that the 'jquery.validity.pack' inclusion is causing problems for the JavaScript compiler in Firefox and Chrome at least. Repositioning it after 'jquery.timeago' and before 'application' seems to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't use the same cache name for different sets of files. Otherwise it will keep getting overwritten in each request..

Comment: Thanks for this - i wasn't aware of it, though it's not the problem happening here :( (turns out only one of the above include tags is only ever being processed)